# How to use wireshark to capture mysql query sql clearly

Tags: mysql, wireshark, tshark

Because we develop using remote `Mysql` server , so cannot check query sql easily, if use local server you can `tail - f general_log_file` to see which sql are executed when call some http interface. So I installed a `wireshark` to capture these query sql send from local. At first I use local mysql to verify it.

The capture filter is 
[image]

then I executed two query sql in mysql terminal

```
select version();
select now();
```

but very disappointing I cannot find these two sql packets in wireshark
[image] 
I only found these four packets.

But from a post I knew

> To filter out the mysql packets you just use the filter ‘mysql‘ or ‘mysql.query != “”‘ when you only want packets that request a query. After that you can add a custom column with the field name ‘mysql.query’ to have a list of queries that where executed.

and the effect is like this
[image]
It's convenient to capture only query sql and very clearly displayed these query sql. So how could I use `wireshark` to implement this?

---

hi @Jeff S.

I tried your command, please see below

```
#terminal 1
tshark -i lo0 -Y "mysql.command==3"
Capturing on 'Loopback'

# terminal 2
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -u root -p
select version();
#result: nothing output in terminal 1
```

and `tshark -i lo0 -Y "mysql.command==3" -T fields -e mysql.query` is same with `tshark -i lo -Y "mysql.command==3"` also nothing output. But if I only use `tshark -i lo0`, it has output

```
Capturing on 'Loopback'
 1   0.000000    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 57881 → 3306 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=16344 WS=32 TSval=1064967501 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
 2   0.000062    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 68 3306 → 57881 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=16344 WS=32 TSval=1064967501 TSecr=1064967501 SACK_PERM=1
 3   0.000072    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 56 57881 → 3306 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=1064967501 TSecr=1064967501
 4   0.000080    127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1    TCP 56 [TCP Window Update] 3306 → 57881 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=408288 Len=0 TSval=1064967501 TSecr=1064967501
...
```

Comment: That is exactly how you have to do it. What happens if you enter this in your filter? The display columns will change with your filter.

Answer (score 8):

You can use tshark and save to a pcap or just export the fields you're interested in.

To save to a pcap (if you want to use wireshark to view later):

```
tshark -i lo -Y "mysql.command==3" -w outputfile.pcap
tshark -i lo -R "mysql.command==3" -w outputfile.pcap
-R is deprecated for single pass filters, but it will depend on your version
-i is interface so replace that with whatever interface you are using (e.g -i eth0)
```

To save to a text file:

```
tshark -i lo -Y "mysql.command==3" -T fields -e mysql.query > output.txt
```

You can also use BPF filters with tcpdump (and wireshark pre cap filters).  They are more complex, but less taxing on your system if you're capturing a lot of traffic.

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo "dst port 3306 and  tcp[(((tcp[12:1]&0xf0)>>2)+4):1]=0x03" -w outputfile.pcap
```

NOTE:
*This looks for 03 (similar mysql.command==3) within the TCP payload.
**Since this is a pretty loose filter, I also added 3306 to restrict to only traffic destined for that port.
***The filter is based on your screenshot.  I cannot validate it right now so let me know if it doesn't work.

Example Output: [image: Sample output from two commands]

Comment: I have tried your way, but it's not success. Please see my post.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked for me.  What version of tshark are you using?  I edited my answer above with a screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! tshark version: `tshark -v
TShark (Wireshark) 2.0.4 (v2.0.4-0-gdd7746e from master-2.0)`; mysql version: 5.7.12; Mac OS X EI Capitan version 10.11.5

Comment: I upgraded to 2.0.4 and I'm able to see the queries.  Try to adjust the commands to see if you can get it to work.  For example, use -Y 'mysql.command>=0' or your original 'mysql.query != “”'   Unfortunately, I don't have access to a mac to verify that.

Comment: hi @Jeff S I tried another `tshark` command, this time it could successfully capture query sql from local to remote mysql server. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Useful answers here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/358978/how-to-capture-the-queries-run-on-mysql-server

In particular: SoMoSparky's answer of:

```
tshark -T fields -R mysql.query -e mysql.query
```

and user1038090's answer of:

```
tcpdump -i any -s 0 -l -vvv -w - dst port 3306 | strings | perl -e '
while(<>) { chomp; next if /^[^ ]+[ ]*$/;
  if(/^(SELECT|UPDATE|DELETE|INSERT|SET|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|CREATE|DROP|ALTER)/i) {
    if (defined $q) { print "$q\n"; }
    $q=$_;
  } else {
    $_ =~ s/^[ \t]+//; $q.=" $_";
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had similar "problem"

Try to check your mysql ssl

Probably the ssl was turned on hence the traffic was encrypted

You can refer to this post to check the ssl: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql

Comment: This. I was seeing data in port 3306 but it didn't make sense and the mysql display filter couldn't do anything. I had to disable the encryption with `mysql -uroot --ssl-mode=DISABLED` which then connected to the server without encryption. Then Wireshark could show the mysql protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I tried another `tshark` command from [this post](https://www.linuxsysadmintutorials.com/how-to-sniff-mysql-traffic-on-a-database-server.html), and it could capture query sql from local to remote mysql server.

```
tshark -i en0 -d tcp.port==3306,mysql -T fields -e mysql.query 'port 3306'
Capturing on 'Wi-Fi'
select version()


select now()


select rand()
```

but it also output some blank lines between these sql. I tried below command want to remove blank line but failed

```
tshark -i en0 -d tcp.port==6006,mysql -Y "frame.len>10" -T fields -e mysql.query 'port 6006'
```

And unfortunately this command cannot support capturing query sql to local mysql(`5.7.12`).

```
tshark -i lo -d tcp.port==3306,mysql -T fields -e mysql.query 'port 3306'
Capturing on 'Loopback'
```

Nothing output except blank lines.

Comment: You're seeing blank lines because the command is not filtering for just queriers.  It also looks like you're now seeing this traffic on en0 rather than lo so try this: tshark -i en0 -Y "mysql.command==3" -T fields -e mysql.query

Comment: Thanks! but use your way nothing output. It seems tshark cannot resolve it correctly in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark tool supports MySQL protocol:
https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mysql.html

Then config wireshark

```
a.menu Analyze --> Decode as --> add "field=tcp_port value=3306  current=MySQL"
b.filter ‘mysql‘ or ‘mysql.query != “”‘
```